# php: convert all relative urls in absolute urls

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-parsing, str-replace

maybe this is an old question but i'm trying as a personal experiment to fetch a page form the web and the make a copy out of it with all the relative urls, links, href, src etc withn absolute urls

i'm using CURL to fetch hte page and I have now a $html variable that contains all the code..

so what; the next step? shoud i use preg_replace? how?

thanks

Comment: "shoud i use preg_replace?" If there is anything you definitely don't need it's a regex. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step is to put it into a HTML parser and to walk the tree, looking for and fixing `href` attributes on `a` tags, `src` attributes on `img` tags, etc etc. The parser will be able to re-emit the tree as a string once you're finished.